# Magento - default values at productcreation

Tags: magento, default, product, creation

kan anyone tell me if/how its possible to predefine some default values when creating a product.

Like: default taxclass, product is "visible" and "in stock".

I hope someone can help me.

Ik have magento 1.6.2 CE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably via config files.

Try, in app/etc/local.xml (or in any config.xml in local/your_package/one_of_your_module/etc/config.xml:

```
<default>
    <cataloginventory>
        <item_options>
            <is_in_stock>1</is_in_stock>
        </item_options>
    </cataloginventory>
</default>
```

Not sure about tax_class_id and visibility, but you may try & go with config.xml as well in order to set or change default values.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.
I tried it in local.xml and config .xml (in app/etc/)
Any other suggestions?

Comment: I just tried in app/etc/local.xml and it works as expected. Also, I did not mention it but the whole should be within the <config/> tag of course. Also, try & refresh your cache. Let us know.

Comment: This works .... thanks
But now i would like to have tax by default on "Hoogtarief" and status "on"

Answer (score 0):

Have a look Ian Baxter's Blog post: [Setting Default Product Values in Magento](http://swarminglabs.com/setting-default-product-values-in-magento/)